# How to create an ASP.net MVC user control with unknown generic type parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, generics, casting

Currently I'm using a base class for some Customer model classes. As defined as follows

```
public abstract class BaseCustomerModel<T>
   where T : IUserEntity
```

For further clarification, the IUserEntity contains:

```
public interface IUserEntity
{
   string ErrorMessage { get; }
}
```

That property among some other things will be exposed in an ErrorTextControl.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<(...).Models.BaseCustomerModel<(...).IUserEntity>>" %>

<tr>
   <td colspan="2"><%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ErrorMessage) %></td>
</tr>
```

I'll call the user control like so:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<(...).Models.MyUserModel>" %>
<% if (Model.HasErrors)
   {
      Html.RenderPartial("ErrorTextControl", Model);
   } %>
```

Last piece of code (MyUserEntity implements IUserEntity):

```
public class MyUserModel : BaseCustomerModel<MyUserEntity>
```

Unfortunately this obviously doesn't work, because the generic type can't be implicitly  casted to an IUserEntity. Therefore resulting in the following error message in the browser:

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   '(...).Models.MyUserModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>    '(...).Models.BaseCustomerModel`1[(...).IUserEntity]'.

So questions:

- Is there any way to define a user control with a generic base class from which the type is not yet known? If yes, how to accomplish such thing?
- If not, any workaround, common solution or ideas to be able to have a generic user control?

Many thanks.

Comment: monty - you'll need some sort of common interface (apart from IUserEntity
) that will be bound. have you identified this??. i say this because you'll be strongly typing sets of properties, therefore these properties will need to be part of a contract. if it's just the IUserEntity part that needs to be exposed to the ErrorTextControl.ascx, then why not: <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IUserEntity>" %>
 - or am i completely missing the point here :)

Comment: Jep, just found out myself too... see the answer I posted.

Comment: good - you know it makes sense!! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just came up with a solution myself.

Just an extra interface to BaseCustomerModel:

```
public abstract class BaseCustomerModel<T> : IContainErrorMessage
   where T : IUserEntity
```

That way the user control doesn't have to worry about the generics:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<(...).Models.IContainErrorMessage>" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>
```

Comment: Well good shot!! It should be with this of course: 'Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<(...).Models.BaseCustomerModel<dynamic>>"', but unfortunately: Compiler Error Message: CS0311: The type 'dynamic' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method '(...).Models.BaseCustomerModel<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'dynamic' to '(...).IUserEntity'.